# jquery functions executes together even from a diffrent button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have 2 buttons and everytime I execute one of them it ends up executing the two functions together one after the other even though they do diffrent actions.
I can't find a way to seperate the two functions in two diffrent buttons without messing the code. I use a variable called key to use in the action.

I tried wrapping them in a div and give them a specific class name yet I didn't succeed into making it work
The functions are at the end

```js
var storage = firebase.storage();
var database = firebase.database();
database.ref('declaration').once('value', function(snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    var content = '';
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      var key = data.key;
      var val = data.val();
      var ker = key + "2";
      var k = key + "1";
      $('#ex-table').append("<tr id='" + key + "'><td>" +
        val.date +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.firstName +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.lastName +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.cin.replace('@gmail.com', '') +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.numTel +
        "</td><td>" +
        "<a href=https://www.google.tn/maps/place/" + val.position + "> My Position </a>" +
        "</td><td>" +
        "<img id='" + k + "' height=200 width=200/>" +
        "</td><td>" +
        val.etat +
        "</td><td><button id='" + key + "'>enoyer equipe</button><button id='" + ker + "'>Delete</button></td></tr>");

      // Fonction de changement d'etat

      var storageRef = storage.ref(val.photo);
      storageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        // Or inserted into an <img> element:
        document.getElementById(k).src = url;
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle any errors
      });

      $(document).on('click', "#" + key, function() {
        var database = firebase.database().ref('declaration')
        var newetat = database.child(key);
        newetat.update({
          "etat": "team sent"
        });
      });
      $(document).on('click', "#" + ker, function() {
        firebase.database().ref('declaration/' + key).remove();
      });
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<table class="table" id="ex-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Date</th>
      <th scope="col">Nom</th>
      <th scope="col">Prénom</th>
      <th scope="col">N° CIN</th>
      <th scope="col">Tel</th>
      <th scope="col">Position</th>
      <th scope="col">Photo d'accident</th>
      <th scope="col">Etat</th>
      <th scope="col">Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I can't see any reason why clicking on one button would run the function for the other button. BTW, there's no need to use event delegation here, since you're adding the event handlers after you add the elements to the DOM.

Comment: Can you replace the Firebase stuff with literal data so we can try to execute your code?

Comment: the buttons start from the td and tr elemets from the table and these are the functions i'm trying to execute 
$(document).on('click', "#" + key, function() {
        var database = firebase.database().ref('declaration')
        var newetat = database.child(key);
        newetat.update({
          "etat": "team sent"
        });
      });
      $(document).on('click', "#" + ker, function() {
        firebase.database().ref('declaration/' + key).remove();
      });
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1) you reused the `id` attribute value `key` (`id` attributes must be unique in HTML documents)

2) You have bound click events to ids `key` and `ker` on elements that are child elements to the `<tr>` element that *also* has a click event bound to it (with the same `id`).

In order to prevent the "bubbling" of the event up the `<tr>` element, add the event reference to the handlers and add:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

inside the handler.

**OR**

use a different `id` on each `<tr>`.

Comment: I tried the event.stopPropagation(); in both of the functions yet it didn't work and keeps on executing the two functions twice.
I tried adding an id to each <tr> and then to each <td> yet the same problem. its probably me not knowing the right way to make it work. can you please try and help me how to fix it with the code.

Comment: @Ramy The problem is that you use `id='" + key+ '"` for the `tr` and also for the `button`. Just use it for one of them.

Comment: since i'm using the key as an Id, I tried making a new one var btkey=key; and used btkey as an id in the button same thing, I think i'm missing something wich probably stupid but I can't figure it out

Comment: There is no reason to have an `id` on the `<tr>` elements at all. Just remove them.